# Splitting a HTML document using lxml.html

Tags: python, html, lxml

I have a HTML document containing multiple chapters of text where the H1 tag is the chapter separator. How can I split such a document into html snippets where each snippet starts with the h1 tag of the corresponding "chapter". I though of prettifying the HTML and then iterating of the content line by line...but that's kind of a hack. Is there a better solution using lxml?

Answer (score 6):

```
tree = lxml.html.document_fromstring(htmltext)
for element in tree.iter():
  if element.tag == 'h1':
    for subelement in element:
      // do stuff
```

That'll find the elements that are h1 tags and then you can iterate through all its subelements. You could also just take all the text inside the element as a string and do stuff with it that way as well. Whatever you want to do.
http://lxml.de/
lxml is awesome and I would recommend it. I had to update code already using it and just kept the website open for reference whenever I had a question :)

Comment: Upvoting because this is not a nonsense answer.

Comment: @user196251 According to every HTML spec, H1 can contain inline elements (such as <a> tags). See [the HTML5 spec's section on H1-H6](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/sections.html#the-h1-h2-h3-h4-h5-and-h6-elements) for more information

Comment: you could also just not use the second for loop and get element.text